# Jenkins pipeline: Accept merge request only if pipeline succeeds

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

unfortunately, despite the abundance of relevant questions, not a single acceptable answer was given until now.

Scenario:

A Merge request triggers a Jenkins pipeline job (done via gitlab webhooks)

The unknown area:

Jenkins pipeline must locally merge (perform) the merge request locally, execute build, tests, integration tests, sonar analysis, etc, and push the merged branch only if all of them succeed.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will give my answer based on my experience with jenkins and GitLab.

When you create a merge a temporary branch is created, so you run the compilation and test on that branch. This is done via a webhook, so each time you create a merge request, it runs the job on jenkins.

On that job, in the post section I have added that only on a success build you call the GitLab's API in order to accept a merge request, as you can see on their documentation here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html

You can make this call using whatever method fits you better to create and send a request to a web server.